# React - Performance with high frequency updates on very large state

Tags: reactjs, performance, websocket, real-time

I making an app which, for some users, handles tens of thousands of real-time sensor data using a websocket connection.

Let's say I am storing the sensor data in one state called "sensorData" and each sensor's data is around 1KB. I will also be receiving an update for a particular sensor every 30 seconds. For 10,000 devices, that means ~300 updates to the state per second. Since state is immutable in React and has to be copied over for any update, that means I will be copying 10,000x1KB = 10MB state in memory 300 times every second (equivalent to copying 10MBx300 = 3000MB per second...) This makes me think that the performance hit will be massive.

Am I perhaps overestimating the performance hit here and it is instead not a big deal? If not, what other options do I have? Can I maybe split this large state into 10,000 states instead (one for each device)? If so, how do I handle and identify all these states and call them all dynamically to retrieve the sensor data?

A couple of notes:

- I have no control over the API, and the way it works is that it just keeps sending data as it comes through a websocket connection.
- I will be using React.Memo to only re-render necessary components. So, I am just asking about the performance hit of updating the state itself, not re-rendering. Although I would appreciate suggestions other than React.Memo here.

**EDIT**
I just realized when copying the state that a shallow copy is happening since I am only changing one sensor's data at a time. So, my estimates are actually wrong. It is probably closer to 8B (reference/pointer) * 10,000 = 80KB to copy over the map references. Then 1KB for the sensor data so 81KB 300 times per second. So overall, it is 81KB x 300 = 24MB per second. I guess it will not have the same performance hit I was thinking of. However, I am still interested if there are better approaches to this. What if we theoretically had 5000 updates per second or we are trying to optimize cpu usage for slower devices?

Comment: It really depends on how you do the copying. So for example if you have an array of 10,000 devices, if each time you do this `topLevelState = topLevelState.map(device => device.id === incoming.id ? incoming : device)` then every update you'll replace the reference to the array, and you'll garbage colllect the old top-level array and the old device that you replaced with the new device info. But this doesn't take into account what your actual data structure is or what state management library you're using.